# Should the name of commandName be always the name of Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my customer JSP page in which the commandName is given as "customerForm":

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="customerForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>UserName : </td>
<td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
<td><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password : </td>
<td><form:password path="password" /></td>
<td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

This is my Controller class which is using the Customer POJO  :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(
            @ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer customer,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

        customerValidator.validate(customer, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            //if validator failed
            return "CustomerForm";
        } else {
            status.setComplete();
            //form success
            return "CustomerSuccess";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String szdfsdf(ModelMap model){

        Customer cust = new Customer();
                model.addAttribute("customerForm", cust);

        //return form view
        return "CustomerForm";
    }
```

Error am getting is :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customerForm' available as request attribute
```

When i have given CommandName="customer" it is working fine. even though the name of ModelAttribute and CommandName is different .

Comment: There shouldn't be a customer attribute in your model. Are having other @ModelAttributes defined in your controller or ControllerAdvice?

Comment: is this related to the Model thing which am setting in model.addAttribute in request method GET ?

Comment: Can you share the whole Controller class code and the JSP file?

Comment: I guess the bottom line is that `commandName` should name the attribute in your model that is to be used. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Bart i think you are correct , i guess i should rename the model name in get method , now it is working fine :) thanks